# How do I force a retina display to always stay on the maximum scaled resolution?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution, catalina

On previous iterations of OS X, and seemingly moreso in Catalina, my MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018), changes the resolution of the retina built-in panel to "Default for display" instead of the Scaled: More Space. Is there some way to force it to always keep the built-in panel on Scaled: More Space?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the model (EG MacBook Pro Mid 2015) of Mac you have

Comment: It's a MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018), but I think any solution (if there is one) would apply to any MacBook with a retina display (I believe the non-retina ones just had a set resolution).

Comment: On my MacBook Air (2018) running Catalina, the resolution keeps resetting itself to "Default" even though I have it set to "More Space". This seems to have just started recently, but I cannot figure out what is causing it. Driving me batty.